# Eulerian path in directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am a math student and am having trouble with the following problem. It would be nice if someone hand me some solution or at least some hint.

Show that in a connected directed graph where every vertex has the same number of incoming as outgoing edges there exists an Eulerian path for the graph.

Comment: The graph needs to be connected (and finite), or there won't be.

Comment: Actually, as I need to prove the existence of a path, I think it should be connected. But, I am not sure. I just wrote down the problem as it has been given to me.

Comment: @Ofogh That assumption is indeed necessary - it should be clear how to construct a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assume that your graph is finite and connected. Once you do that, a possible plan of attack would be

1. Show that $G$ contains at least one tour (that is, a cycle without repeated edges).
2. Let $A$ any tour that is not Eulerian, and show that it is not maximal:

   - Show that there is an edge not in $A$ that begins at a vertex visited by $A$.
   - Show that there is a tour in $G\setminus A$ which starts at this vertex.
   - Now you have two disjoint tours with a vertex in common. Show that they can be combined into a tour whose length is the sum of the lengths.
3. Since the graph is finite, there is a maximum possible length of a tour. But by (2), a tour that has this maximal length must be Eulerian.